# Attaching a file to messages (Wordpress User Messaging

Tags: wordpress

I have a plugin (User Messaging for WP) and I need to enable my users to attach a file to their messages (they can talk to one another)

This is the advice I've got:
"the change should be implemented by replacing the function in line 363."

This is the line:

```
function messaging_new_message_notification($tmp_to_uid,$tmp_from_uid,$tmp_subject,$tmp_content) {
```

Can you all please elaborate which function should be added?
The plugin enables users to send messages to eachother, when they are logging into their wordpress dashboard they can see it in their inbox.
I want them to be able to send files also, so that the files will be kept in the WP DB.

This is the plugin (the basic freemium version is enough)
https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/messaging/

This is the original file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8p1x28ydbmyp2gm/messaging.php.orig

I've tried to add the $attachments = "; and the $tmp_attachment but probably did it the wrong way...

here is what I've tried:

```
function messaging_new_message_notification($tmp_to_uid,$tmp_from_uid,$tmp_subject,$tmp_content,$tmp_attachment) {
global $wpdb, $current_site, $user_ID, $messaging_email_notification_subject, $messaging_email_notification_content;

if (is_multisite()) {
    $SITE_NAME  = $current_site->site_name;
    $SITE_URL   = 'http://'. $current_site->domain;
} else {
    $SITE_NAME  = get_option('blogname');
    $SITE_URL   = get_option('siteurl');
}

if (get_user_meta($tmp_to_uid,'message_email_notification') != 'no'){
    $tmp_to_username =  $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT user_login FROM " . $wpdb->users . " WHERE ID = %d", $tmp_to_uid));
    $tmp_to_email =  $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT user_email FROM " . $wpdb->users . " WHERE ID = %s", $tmp_to_uid));
    $tmp_from_username =  $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT user_login FROM " . $wpdb->users . " WHERE ID = %d", $tmp_from_uid));

    $message_content = get_site_option('messaging_email_notification_content', $messaging_email_notification_content);

    $message_content = str_replace( "SITE_NAME", $SITE_NAME, $message_content );
    $message_content = str_replace( "SITE_URL", $SITE_URL, $message_content );

    $message_content = str_replace( "TO_USER", $tmp_to_username, $message_content );
    $message_content = str_replace( "FROM_USER", $tmp_from_username, $message_content );
    $message_content = str_replace( "\'", "'", $message_content );

    $subject_content = get_site_option('messaging_email_notification_subject', $messaging_email_notification_subject);
    $subject_content = str_replace( "SITE_NAME", $SITE_NAME, $subject_content );

    $admin_email = get_site_option('admin_email');
    if ($admin_email == ''){
        $admin_email = 'admin@' . $current_site->domain;
    }
    $from_email = $admin_email;

    $message_headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "From: " . $SITE_NAME .  " <{$from_email}>\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"" . get_option('blog_charset') . "\"\n";
    wp_mail($tmp_to_email, $subject_content, $message_content, $message_headers);
```

I don't need it to be sent to the email, just to appear in the message inside the WP dashboard

Thanks in advanced

Comment: no the basic plugin is free and although I'm using the premum version the basic one is enough for helping me

Answer (score 0):

You are going to right way just missing something to add in `wp_mail()` function.

After adding this in your function

```
function messaging_new_message_notification($tmp_to_uid,$tmp_from_uid,$tmp_subject,$tmp_content,$tmp_attachment) {
```

you have to add

```
wp_mail($tmp_to_email, $subject_content, $message_content, $message_headers, $tmp_attachment);
```

For more information take a look on [WP_Mail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail) the fifth variable of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much dear Jogesh.
Actually I've found out that using a plugin that let me control the attributes of my users I could enable WP Media and it appears automatically so I deleted all of my code rewrites...
The plugin I'm using is:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager/